I am facing an issue implementing ADM in AWS for push notifications
I am using this URL to set up ADM: https://developer.amazon.com/docs/adm/integrate-your-app.html?cmp=US_2022_05_CON_ADM-Tutorial&ch=soc&chlast=soc&pub=yub&publast=yub&type=org&typelast=org
Please suggest a solution to this issue.
Error:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/amazon/device/messaging/ADM;
                at com.schok.notification.NotificationActivity.onCreate(NotificationActivity.kt:16)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8523)
                at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8487)
                at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1438)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3815)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3980)
                at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:101)
                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
                at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
                at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2394)
                at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
                at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:211)
                at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:300)
                at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8296)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:559)
                at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:954)
               Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.amazon.device.messaging.ADM" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/~~vxTmTvSCwgVFhn5cVNTHcA==/com.schok.notification-uaEqOfRR3zWEepzTjsia8Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/~~vxTmTvSCwgVFhn5cVNTHcA==/com.schok.notification-uaEqOfRR3zWEepzTjsia8Q==/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /system_ext/lib64]]
                at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:259)

Is there any other way to implement push notifications without using Google services or paid services?

You are missing the library classes.
Adding ADM to Android Studio

I have added the jar. but it showing Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Stub! You are bundling a stubbed jar in the apk! Please move it to the classpath instead.
